# Concatenating 32-bit int chunks in 16 char array in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have a result buffer of the following data type:

```
 char result[16];
```

The problem is, that the result is computed in 4 chunks of 32 bits
each, that need to be assigned to the 128-bit result char.

```
int res_tmp[0] = 0x6A09E667;
int res_tmp[1] = 0x6A09E612;
int res_tmp[2] = 0x6A09E432;
int res_tmp[3] = 0x6A09E123;
```

Ideally, there should be something like an concatenation operator in C, e.g.,

```
result = res_tmp[0] || res_tmp[1] || res_tmp[2] || res_tmp[3];
```

Finally, the result needs to be send over a socket as follows:

```
while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, 
                          (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                          &address_length)) > -1)
{
  n = write(connection_fd, result, strlen(result));
  if (n < 0) printf("Error writing to socket\n");            
  close(connection_fd);
  break;  
}
```

Anyone knows the easiest syntax for concatenating the 32-bit words in the 128-bir result `char`?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Are we talking about bits or bytes? What do you think `char[128]` means?

Comment: Good point, the result char should be 128-bits, that is 16 bytes. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: `strlen()` is a bad choice for computing the length of the `result` array. Try `sizeof result` or even just `16`.

Comment: I really don't understand the question.Bytes, bits, chars, ints? What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must decide if the `char` array is representing the result in big-endian or little endian order. If the endian-ness of your processor and the array happen to coincide, you can use a `union`:

```
union myunion
{
    char result[16];
    int res_tmp[4];
};
```

Then you don't have to copy at all.

If you need the opposite endian-ness of your processor, you can use [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) res_tmp[i] = htonl(res_tmp[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just use `memcpy` ?

```
memcpy(result, res_tmp, sizeof(res_tmp));
```

Also note that `strlen` is for null terminated strings, you should use sizeof for static buffer:

```
n = write(connection_fd, result, sizeof(result));
```

And of course you could just send `res_tmp`

```
n = write(connection_fd, (char*)res_tmp, sizeof(res_tmp));
```

Comment: And why not a simple pointer? He doesn't need to copy the memory.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I think I say that in the last line

Answer (score -1):

Basically the standard technique is to create an int pointer and point it at the char array, then use it to write the data in. Something like this

```
int temp_res[4]; //the calculated ints
char result[16]; //the target buffer
int *ptr=(int *)result;
for (int i=0;i<4;i+=1) {
  *ptr=temp_res[i];
  ptr++; //move up a int size because ptr is an int type
}
```

Comment: Pointers arithmetic: you move an int pointer of sizeof(int) bytes away with ptr++, if you say ptr+=sizeof(int) and the int is 4 bytes on your machine, you move it of 4 positions and 16 bytes in total.

Comment: `int *ptr=(int *)result` results in undefined behavior, same as Ramy Al Zuhouri's answer.

Comment: @bames53 didn't get a chance to ask because the question was deleted, I wanted to know an example of how the alignment for char array could be different than int array and thanks for the info :)

Comment: @mux The issue is that in general there's just no guarantee that the storage for an object of one type is suitable for an object of a different type. `char c[sizeof(int)];` may legally produce an array that is not aligned for an int. Different compilers show various levels of aggressiveness in forcing alignment: http://ideone.com/cH7enS. (gcc seems to be quite aggressive, msvc less so, clang displays no inclination to over-align char arrays (except where required by the standard, or course) but instead offers the `-Wcast-align` warning).